# Creating asymmetric cells to a QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

Is it possible to chain setSpan() -calls or use it in a way so that the spanned area would start from a cell of a first column to the end of that same column, and then continue from the beginning of the second column?

To clarify, I'm creating a calendar application, where I have a table for a week-view (each column represents a weekday, and each row represents an hour of time). I have successfully used the setSpan-function to represent how much time an entry in the calendar takes, but I have a problem when a single entry spans multiple days. For example, if an entry starts on Monday at 8 pm and lasts until Tuesday at 12 am, the cell holding the entry should span the last four cells of the Monday-column and the first twelve cells of the Tuesday-column.

I'm quite new to Qt so I don't know if there are better ways to accomplish this than setSpan, but I have searched quite extensively for a solution to my problem and have found none. It guess it would be equally helpful if I could somehow make the same item to be shown in multiple cells of the same table, but I haven't found a way to do this either.